# How to configure bash to prompt history?

Tags: bash

With fish-shell, if I type a few words of a ran command, I will get a prompt of the whole command line. Then I just use Right Arrow key to complete the whole line.

But on other things, fish-shell sucks. So how could I do this prompt thing in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for bash to automatically fill in the command line from history. Performing `reverse-search-history`, bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> by default, will allow you to type in part of a command which bash will then attempt to find in history. Performing it while doing a search will find older matches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is a way activate a search for command from history.
I also like this kind of things in tcsh.
To retrieve your last commands from history you should:
1) add file .inputrc in your home directory
2) restart shell
3) start typing beginning of your last wanted command
4) and then hit ESC+p  or  ESC+n

~/.inputrc should be like this:

### tcsh behavior in bash:

### ESC+p  and  ESC+n  (or M+p and M+n) will give non-increment history

### completion backwards and forward, respectively

"\ep": history-search-backward

"\en": history-search-forward